# RewriteRule without parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect /cart.php?whatever to /flow.php (I don't care about parameters after cart.php), so I wrote this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^cart.php flow.php$ [R=301,L]
```

but it redirect to /flow.php?whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^cart.php flow.php? [R=301,L]
```